# How to show list have mixed rows that can be deleted while some rows that cannot be deleted?

Tags: lists, users, checkboxes

Hope you enjoying WFM. I had a query, we are showing a list of both external and internal users. While internal users are federated and cannot be deleted. Only external users can be deleted. We have two conditions to be fulfilled :

**1. Both type of users to be assigned roles. Multi-select users and assign them to the role.**

**2. Multi-select users and delete them ( only external users )**

So since we have two type of behaviors showing them together, I am facing problem if a user selects both types then what to show

[image]

[image]

It would be really helpful any suggestions to get rid of this roadblock. Be safe

Answer (score 1):

Showing numbers next to bulk actions may ease the case. For example, if user select 5 users which 2 of them can not be deleted, bulk action will show: Assign role[5] , Delete[3]. By doing this, you are allowing user to perform every action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even in that view, it won't be clear which users he's assigning and which users he's going to delete

Comment: Yep that's right, but is that important to see which of them? Because, I'm thinking this as a role management problem rather than a visualization problem. So the primary aim here is to allow actions which user can perform, rather than showing the exact deletable people. If s/he can't delete them, obviously s/he shouldn't be deleting them at the first place or needs higher administrative role.